# Trap ERR strange behaviour (infinite loop) depending on how function is defined

Tags: function, shell, unix, ksh

Hope somebody can help with this - not sure if this is a known bug with ksh93?

```
#!/bin/ksh93
_errorCheck()
{
        LINENO=$1
        print "Error on or near line $LINENO - please check error log"
        exit 1
}
trap '_errorCheck ${LINENO}' ERR

false
```

This ouputs:

```
 Error on or near line 10 - please check error log
```

However...if the function is defined using the word function instead of ():

```
#!/bin/ksh93
function _errorCheck 
{
        LINENO=$1
        print "Error on or near line $LINENO - please check error log"
        exit 1
}
trap '_errorCheck ${LINENO}' ERR

false
```

This then outputs:

```
Error on or near line 10 - please check error log
Error on or near line 10 - please check error log
Error on or near line 10 - please check error log
Error on or near line 10 - please check error log
Error on or near line 10 - please check error log
Error on or near line 10 - please check error log
```

What seems to be an infinite amount of times...

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

As requested:
KSH_VER=Version M-12/28/93e

Comment: Do you have the errexit shell option set?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, with or without the `-e` option.

Comment: @bgoldst - Still seeing the same with/without set -e

Comment: please add the output of `echo KSH_VER=${.sh.version}` to your post. Good luck.

Comment: @chepner - I am running AIX, not sure if ksh93 is a bit iffy on here, for example named pipes aren't supported

Comment: Hm, I'm running `KSH_VER=Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01` on Mac OS X, so if it's a problem in an older version of `ksh`, I'm afraid I can't be of further help.

Comment: oh .... AIX ksh ... hard for most of us to confirm this behavior. You probably work in an organization where getting a newer version installed will be a bureaucratic night-mare. You might find some extra help on http://ittoolbox.com . There are AIX people there (in an AIX specific group) that may have some insight to this. In the future, be sure to include an AIX tag on your posts when approriate. There are a lot of differences between AIX and Linux or even OSX, Sun etc. (as you seem to know). Sorry, and good luck.

Comment: I reproduced this with mksh. I'm still trying to figure out why it's happening though. Also (https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/mksh.htm) has some documentation on the difference between using "function" and "bourne style ()" functions. Search for "Functions defined with the function".

Comment: A temporary solution for now would be to remove the "exit 1" from the 2nd function. For some reason it looks like the trap isn't resetting upon execution in the 2nd example, so when an error is triggered, it starts a cascade of errors since the function returns an error and so forth. I'm guessing that the specialness and locality of the 2nd "ksh function" is coming into play here.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys - its not an issue as I can workaround it as has been mentioned, just thought it was a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

Using `function f {...}` and `f() {...}` it's actually different in ksh. You can check this answer which explains very well what you are experimenting.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73750/difference-between-function-foo-and-foo

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line

```
trap - ERR
```

at the top of either function to reset the trap after it first triggers.

For me the second function shows expected behaviour.

Anyway, you experimented and found something that works.  That's all that matters.